# APC on PHP 5.3.10/Apache 2.2.21

Tags: php, apc

I tried to install APC on my wamp(PHP 5.3.10/Apache2.2.21). OS which i`m using is Windows 7.

I downloaded 'APC 3.1.9 for PHP 5.3 vc9 (Win7/2008)' dll from http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc.html.

I copied php_apc.dll to wamp/php/5.3.10/ext and I added extension=php_apc.dll to php.ini file.

phpinfo() don`t display APC configuration, and APC is not working. 
phpinfo() values Compiler:MSVC9, Architecture:x86, Enabled for Thread Safety.

Thank you

Comment: If it don't show in phpinfo(). Then php_apc.dll isn't compatible. Is your windows 64 or 32 bit ? Try google with it.

Comment: I have 64bit windows. I tried all kinds of php_apc.dll but non seems to be compatible.

Comment: Did you finally solved it? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this guide it solved the problem for me.

http://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/installing-apc-3-1-6-on-wamp-64-bit/

You can see why here:

http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,70601